# Why can't I stride over all Strideable types in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, iteration

I get an error:

> Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: MyType, to: MyType, by: MyType)'

when I try to compile this code:

```
typealias MyType = UInt64

let a: MyType = 0
let b: MyType = 100
let c: MyType = 10

for i in stride(from: a, to: b, by: c) {
  // …
}
```

What's odd is that when I jump to the definition of `Swift.stride` it shows that stride should take basically any `Strideable`:

```
public func stride<T>(from start: T, to end: T, by stride: T.Stride) -> StrideTo<T> where T : Strideable
```

But if I add `extension MyType: Strideable {}` to my code, it complains that "Conformance of 'UInt64' to protocol 'Strideable' was already stated in the type's module 'Swift'"!

Why won't it let me stride over anything but an Int?

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is with the `by stride:` parameter. Upon closer inspection, its expected type is not `T`, but `T.Stride` — and `UInt64.Stride` is *not* typealiased to `UInt64`, but to `Int`!

The following code satisfies the type requirements of `stride`'s third parameter:

```
typealias MyType = UInt64

let a: MyType = 0
let b: MyType = 100
let c: MyType = 10

for i in stride(from: a, to: b, by: Int(c)) {
  // …
}
```

(If practical in your code, I would recommend typing `c` as an `Int` initially instead. In my original context that didn't make as much sense as "casting" it only during its usage with `stride`.)

Comment: Excellent sleuthing (Voted.) This obtuse error message would have defeated me.